# UK Visa Refusal twice

Tags: visas, uk, terminology

I have been refused UK Visa twice, in 2015 and 2016, I am about reapplying for another one again. I want to get all the document that they said was not in my application and reapply again, in the next two weeks, I want to know if I will be considered or will I be refused.

Comment: 1. Look at the reasons for your previous refusals. 2. Address those issues before you apply again or you're likely to end up with the same result.

Comment: Check the refusal conditions on your refusal letters. There are multitude of questions on UK visa refusals with answers on this website, which should help you in putting a proper application this time.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if I will be considered or will I be refused.

Just a brief note on 'consideration'.

The act of paying the fee for a visa (currently GBP 87) provides the individual with *consideration* of their application.  So assuming you paid the fee successfully, then yes your application will be duly considered by a British national who has a mandate from the government to make decisions on entry clearance applications.

The *outcome* of the decision-making process is a different matter entirely, and the fee does not cover this.

> will be considered or will I be refused

Both.  Or alternatively, your application will be considered and granted.

It seems a small point, but if you are dealing with them in a formal context, like a complaint or appeal, it helps to distinguish between the two.